# where to specify file name and path when logging exceptions in java?

Tags: java

I'm new to java and trying to learn how to log an exception by example. I found the following example code here:

http://www.kodejava.org/examples/447.html

However, I don't see where the filename for the log file is specified. When I research the question on Google usually people refer to the framework used for programming java to figure out where the log file gets stored. However, I'm not using a framework. I'm just creating my java files using VIM editor from the command line. The java file sits on an Linux CentOS application server and is called from a client's browser.

Question 1: Is it possible to modify the example below to include a file name and path for logging? Or, am I way off base with this question?

Question 2: Even though I log the exception, will it still propagate to the client for the user to view? Hopefully it will, otherwise the user won't know an error has occurred.

```
package org.kodejava.example.util.logging;

import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;

public class LoggingException {
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoggingException.class.getName());

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    df.setLenient(false);

    try {
        //
        // Try to parsing a wrong date.
        //
        Date date = df.parse("12/30/1990");

        System.out.println("Date = " + date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        //
        // Create a Level.SEVERE logging message
        //
        if (logger.isLoggable(Level.SEVERE)) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error parsing date", e);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: For question 2 - out of curiosity, how is this being called from a user's browser?  Your code doesn't render any HTML which is what a browser understands...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
try {
    FileHandler handler = new FileHandler("myLogFile.log", true);
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoggingException.class.getName());
    logger.addHandler(handler);
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error parsing date", e);
}
```

By default, a file handler overwrites the contents of the log file each time it is created. You might also want to append log file so in FileHandler constructor you need to specify `true` as a second parameter.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

```
package org.kodejava.example.util.logging;

import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;

public class LoggingException {
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoggingException.class.getName());

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    df.setLenient(false);
    FileHandler handler = new FileHandler("myLogFile.log", true);
    logger.addHandler(handler);
    try {
        //
        // Try to parsing a wrong date.
        //
        Date date = df.parse("12/30/1990");

        System.out.println("Date = " + date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        //
        // Create a Level.SEVERE logging message
        //
        if (logger.isLoggable(Level.SEVERE)) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error parsing date", e);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

This should work. I did not test it. 
More efficient way would be create a method to initialize logger and add handler to it. But I will mostly recommend you to think about using `log4j`. It is easy to set up and widely used logging framework.

Comment: Thanks Paulius, where does this code get placed in the example above? For example, does it replace everything inside the `catch (ParseException e) { ... }` block? Also, once logged, will the error propagate to user to view it, or do I need to use `throws Exception` when I declare the function (if so, does that change anything in your answer)?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Take a look. If you want to view exception in the console you also need to specify ConsoleHandler. Than messages will be logged into the file and into the console.

Answer (score 1):

You need a FileHandler attached to the log, which you can add manually somewhere in your initialization, or configure your logging with a .properties file.

(p.s. the isLoggable call in this example is redundant and only bloats the code)

Answer (score 1):

Add a file handler for the logger in the config.
Link: http://www.crazysquirrel.com/computing/java/logging.jspx

```
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler, java.util.logging.FileHandler
```

Better go with log4j. It a good logging framework.